# General to Date in EXCEL

Tags: excel, date

I have a general column that contains data but the date is in this format:

- 12301988
- 2091988

when I tried to convert it to short-date , it will be like this :

- #
- 8/31/7627

What I wanted is like this:

- 12/30/1988
- 2/09/1988

How can I resolve this?

Comment: how do you know that `2091988` is not `20/9/1988`  is the month always two digits?

Comment: Because other cells contain info like that:4071989 which should be 4/07/1989....40/7/1989.... is not possible right?so I guess its always 2 digit for date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you will need to parse the different parts:

```
=DATE(RIGHT(A1,4),LEFT(A1,IF(LEN(A1)=8,2,1)),MID(A1,LEN(A1)-5,2))
```

[image]

---

Or use this:

```
=--REPLACE(REPLACE(A1,IF(LEN(A1)=8,5,4),0,"/"),IF(LEN(A1)=8,3,2),0,"/")
```

And format as short date.

[image]